# using python to create columns in csv files using info from other csv files

Tags: python, csv, glob

So I have a number of csv files each containing a datetime column and a 'value' column. Each csv corresponds to a location which is denoted by an id number for each file. So that each file is named for example 111111.csv.

I then have a separate csv file with a list of these id numbers with the corresponding latitude and longitude in columns 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

What i would like to do is using the id numbers create columns in the individual csv files for latitude and longitude and then fill these in with the correct value.

So what im anticipating is the csv files to have four columns datetime, value, latitude, longitude.

I am also expecting each latitude value to be the same and each longitude to be the same for every data point in each csv as each csv represents an individual location.

I am aware how to use glob to identify the csv files within the directory and have previously created new columns in every file in a directory but am unsure how to use the separate csv to fill in what i want.

Thanks

EDIT

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("342304.0.csv")
df["latitude"] = 14.25
df["longitude"] = -61.25
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

i have this code that does it individually but i would like to iterate over all the filenames add latitude and longitude columns to all of them and then fill them in with the correct latitude and longitude values which I have in a separate csv

each csv is like

datetime, value

where the datetime is formatted like 1979-01-01 07:00:00 and the value is just a number

and then the reference file is formatted

fid, latitude, longitude

where fid is the file id and corresponds to the title of the other csvs and their corresponding lat longs

```
 import pandas as pd
 import glob

 reference = pd.read_csv("reference.csv")

 files =glob.glob('*csv')

 for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['latitude'] = reference.latitude when reference.fid = filename
    df.to_csv(file)
```

This is kinda how I imagine it looking but i know that the second line of for file in files is wrong but not entirely sure how to get it to do what i want

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide us with the code you have for this task, and why it isn't working (either because of an error, or an incorrect output). As is, your question is unclear.

Comment: It would help to have sample data. Say 3 csv files with 2 rows plus an id file for those 3 csvs. Then we can work on a solution without having to cook the data.